# My Force Download through php headers starts way too slow for it to be acceptable for commercial use

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin on my wordpress website, which handles the download section. I have been trying to optimize the plugin because the download starts way too slow for it to be acceptable for commercial use.

The plugin is running through PHP, I don't know if I am doing anything wrong in my code. If I am not doing anything wrong it means the hosting is the issue?

Here is the code that handles the download section:

```php
try
{
$url = $ed_form_downloadurl;
set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
header('Connection: close');
echo $r;
die();
}
```

If there are things you would like me to clear feel free to ask.

Comment: How does cURL fit into this situation? Download, to me, implies that you are delivering files from your server to a browser not going to another machine to get a file.

Comment: Does it mean that cURL is unnecessary and might be taking speed?

Comment: cURL will certainly add overhead. If the file you are trying to deliver is already on your server use `readfile` and deliver it directly rather than using cURL to get a copy (from who knows where .... it isn't clear in your question).

Comment: The files are added to the database through query, and I add an ID that will be used to fetch which files are being downloaded. 

Then the link for downloading will be made and this link is sent to the users through email.